# Doctrine em fetch associate data in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, doctrine

I'm working on codeigniter doctrine orm , setup everything but don't know how to fetch data!
having two tables 'user' and 'firm' , wanted to load user with their firms.
Tried this way also ,

```
$records = $em->getRepository("Entities\YourTargetEntity")->findAll();
```

But its not working , 
My controller function is,

```
public function index()
{
    $em = $this->doctrine->em->user;
    $records = $em->getRepository("Entities\user")->findAll();
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($records);die;
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
```

Note:I've added firm_id to user table as foreign key. So what i need is '**How to fetch mapped data in doctrine (CI)**?'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the code is as follows:

```
$userRepository = $this->doctrine->em->getRepository('Entities\user');
$records = $userRepository->findAll();
```

The findAll() method is available in Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository class:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html#158-166